# Removing "this" index of array not working

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, time

This is my code:

```
var x = [{letter: "a"}, {letter: "b"}, {letter: "c"}]

x.push({
    timer: setTimeout(function() {x.splice(x.length - 1, 1)}, 3000),
    letter: "j",
})

x.push({letter: "k"})

setTimeout(function() {alert(x)}, 4000)
```

And my main question is: Why does the code alert "a,b,c,[A number]" when it should alert "a,b,c,k", why does it delete the wrong index?

Comment: Why are you doing this exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x.splice(x.length, 1)` removes one element starting at `x.length`, which is outside the bounds of the array; use `x.splice(x.length - 1, 1)`, or just `x.pop()`.

If the idea is for the object to remove itself from the array, store the length before you add it and use that:

```
var removeIndex = x.length;

x.push({
    timer: setTimeout(function() { x.splice(removeIndex, 1); }, 3000),
    letter: "j",
});
```

Comment: I accept this answer but I now really found out what the problem in my real code was, please check the edited question

Comment: @Murplyx: Okay, why do you think it should print `a,b,c,k`? You have `a,b,c`. Then you `push` whatever `setTimeout` returned. Then you push `k`. Then you remove the last item, which is `k`.

Comment: Yes but it should delete the setTimeout and not the k

Comment: @Murplyx: So you want to delete the second-to-last item, not the last one? `x.splice(x.length - 2, 1)`. Arrays are zero-based.

Comment: @Murplyx: You're misunderstanding in one of at least two ways. 1) Only the callback passed to the  `setTimeout` call is delayed. Not the return value of the `setTimeout` call. 2) The state of `x` and its `.length` is evaluated when the callback is invoked. They're not evaluated when you pass the callback to `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Yes I want it to be evaluated before that's it

Comment: @Murplyx: Simply  because that's not how it works. Functions create closures that reference the variables within its scope. They don't take any sort of snapshot or copy of the variables. Therefore when the function is invoked, it looks up the variable from its scope and reads its current value.

Comment: @Murplyx: So keep the index as shown. It’s just not going to work without keeping the old index or finding it again.

Comment: @Murplyx: If your actual situation is more complex and it isn't convenient to store the index in an variable, you may just want to iterate the `x` Array and do a simple comparison of each object until the correct one is found.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that, but isn't there a simpler solution for my complex situation which in I can't store the index in a variable?

Comment: @Murplyx: That’s about as simple as it can be made, I think.

Comment: Well, finally I fixed it using date-changes instead of setTimeout

Comment: -1 because…? (If it’s a valid complaint, I like to know, is all.)

Answer (score 0):

```
x.push(setTimeout(function() {x.splice(x.length - 1, 1)}, 3000))
```

This will actually push the timeoutID onto the array.  This is followed by an additional push `x.push('k')`, so the `k` element actually gets removed when the timeout resolves.

`x.length` will change inside of the timeout function.  If you want to use the index of the element you are about to add, store `x.length` as a variable in a higher scope.

http://jsfiddle.net/rrw3s/

Comment: @Murplyx as I said, don't use `x.push` with `setTimeout`.  Remove the `x.push` statement